# Turn an external hard-drive into an internal one (ubuntu server)

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have an old 1tb external hard drive with enclosure and a new HP ProLiant G7 N54L 2.2GHz MicroServer running a freshly installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.

**Spec:**

> - AMD N54L / 2.2GHz
> - 2GB DDR3 SDRAM
> - HDD 1x 250GB

My external hard drive enclosure has recently failed but I have no reason to believe there is a problem with the hard drive (or it's contents itself).

I would like to:

1. Retrieve the data on my external hard drive and secure it on my new server
2. Add the 1tb hard drive to server so that the total space available is 1250 gb (probably with RAID but i need to read up on this separately).

How can I add the 1TB external to my hard drive rack so that it's readable by Ubuntu server in order to copy all the data across?

Then I would be interested to hear any recommendations or reasoning for a particular hard drive setup (I'll be wanting to use this box for a small amount of Drupal hosting, owncloud and possibly FTP).

Cheers community!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a USB universal drive adapter [like this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002) is generally the easiest way to retrieve data from a drive with a failed enclosure.

Depending on the type of drive (IDE, SATA) and size (2.5" or 3.5"), it may be possible to just plug it into a drive bay on your server and have it read - Ubuntu is pretty good at being able to read most filesystems.

Read up on RAIDs - pairing a 250GB and 1TB drive in a RAID of most any type is not going work well. Better to have them as separate volumes.

Comment: And, OBTW, if an answer to your question is good, please click on the checkmark-on-circle icon at left to show it was good. You can change that later if a better answer comes up which meets your needs more directly. This also adds karma points to your rep.

Comment: Excellent douggro, many thanks. Especially interesting about the RAID point with the two drive sizes.

Comment: When raid you really want a true RAID controller,